# Check if term is in a taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, terms

Is there a function that does something like:

```
is_in_taxonomy($term, $taxonomy)
```

Where it returns true if `$taxonomy` has that `$term`. ????

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [**`term_exists()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists):

```
<?php term_exists( $term, $taxonomy, $parent ); ?>
```

`$term` is **required** (obviously).

Both `$taxonomy` and `$parent` are optional, but if you want to determine if a *specific* taxonomy has a given term, just pass the registered taxonomy name via the `$taxonomy` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[`term_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

```
term_exists( $term, $taxonomy );
```